# How to call default windows credential in my code?

Tags: c++, windows, credential-providers

I have my own implementation of "windows credential provider".
In some scenarios my custom credential must switch to windows default credential and the user must see the "windows credential provider" to do the login process.
How can I exit my own "credential" and call the default "windows credential"?

Comment: LogonUI ? Windows Version ?
If you can't see the tile of the default Credential Provider, you most likely disabled it.

Comment: No, the problem is how to call(fire) another "credential" (in this question windows credential) and exit current credential? the problem is about any windows version. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In new scenario of Microsoft Windows's Credential Providers, you can't direct which other provider user must use to log on to the system.

The only thing you can do is to force logon using your own provider or decline logon using your provider.

To do this you must:

1. Set `pdwDefault` to any useful value and `pbAutoLogonWithDefault` to `true` inside of call to `GetCredentialCount`.
2. Set the `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE *pcpgsr` parameter inside of `GetSerialization` method to one of the following values:

   - `CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED` - to do auto-logon,
   - `CPGSR_RETURN_NO_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED` - to cancel logon UI process.

In any case your provider (tile) will loose the focus. Check out this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/credentialprovider/ne-credentialprovider-credential_provider_get_serialization_response).

**Update**

You can remove your provider from entire logon process by returning `E_NOTIMPL` value from inside of the call to `SetUsageScenario` method.

User and/or Logon UI will be forced to use any other existing provider(s).

Comment: Thanks a lot! please clear me how can i access to *pcpgsr variable and change it in a CommandLinkClicked(DWORD dwFieldID)? i only can access it, when  GetSerialization() is called by provider.

Comment: Inside of event handler `CommandLinkClicked` you have no chances, only inside of `GetSerialization`.

Answer (score 0):

LogonUI searches for all 'enabled' credential provider on the system and call GetCredentialCount to get all credentials for each particular Provider.

One thing you can do is calling ICredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged which will ask logonUI to 'refresh' the tiles. 
You can disable your provider and enable the default one in some way before calling the event.

Another way to do it is to implement your own password credential in your provider i guess. This way, you can choose the index of the credential compared to the others.