# Credential provider strange results on rebooting

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, credential-providers

I have created a custom Credential provider that I am attempting to use for auto logon. I am using the a Microsoft sample for implementing

```
case CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION:
   _cpus = cpus;
   _fRecreateEnumeratedCredentials = true;
   hr = S_OK;
```

I have set

```
ICredentialProvider::GetCredentialCount
pbAutoLogonWithDefault = TRUE;

ICredentialProviderCredential2::SetSelected 
pbAutoLogon = TRUE;
```

I also set a username and password within the GetSerialization() that is currently a local login.

I get some really strange behaviour with the provider as when I start the Windows 10 machine the account appears to login, I can see that Mail and Skype appear on the screen on the bottom right. But dosn't fully unlock the desktop, I have to click the screen or press Ctrl+Alt+Delete and then click the login button on the provider. What is strange is that the user profile is fully logged in. I just need to remove this splash screen.

[image]

If I logout with the current profile on the machine, where I am prompted with the credential provider and Sign in button as the image below.

[image]

If I restart the machine by clicking the power button on bottom left, the machine restarts and logs into the machine and I have access to the desktop.

I am looking to achieve an auto logon with the credential provider.

Comment: Did you use C or C++? Please do only add the one you actually used

Comment: Apologies i must have added the C tag without realising

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165396/3868464).