# Why I need to implement credential provider

Tags: windows, winapi, credential-providers

I have a machine which gets locked if no interaction is done after 15 minutes and when right time comes I want to unlock it programmatically because my program does some things which needs UI. Of course I can disable the screen locking entirely but let's consider that this is not an option.

I've googled and found out that I need to implement credential provider for this but I don't understand why. I guess I don't know the internal workings of the windows. If I know the username/password of the user or even when user doesn't have a password I can use why I need to implement the credential provider? I've read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows) on Windows website and it seems like windows already has "System credential providers" but I could not found how I can interact with them (Maybe you can't and that's why everybody suggest to implement third party CP) Can somebody please explain how screen locking on windows works and why is that impossible to unlock the screen without implementing CP? thanks

Comment: Have a look at this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165396/3868464).

Answer (score 0):

If your machine locks, it will require some kind of credentials to be passed back through the LSA to unlock it. It is best to prevent the machine from locking in the first place.

If you pursue a strategy using a credential provider, you will need to find a way of securely recording and replaying the user's password. The credential provider will also put up a 'sign in' button as a 'road block' (Microsoft's term) to force user interaction when logging in.