# why some account can auto login some account can not?

Tags: winapi, credential-providers, windows-credential-provider

i implement `GetCredentialCount` and `GetSerialization` and other function to control windows auto login. one account can auto login, but another account can not auto login. how can i modify configuration to auto login successful ?

- succ
  [image: autologin1]
- fail
  another account can not auto login, login ui show a user i set auto login, i click the user and it logining whitout input password.
  [image: autologin2]

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Turn on automatic logon in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon)

Comment: That's not what I want. I want to use code to control

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165396/3868464).